# Alternative to Marmalade for Cocos2d-x v3.13.1?

Tags: cocos2d-x, marmalade, cocos2d-x-2.x, cocos2d-x-3.x

I was using Marmalade to easily build my Cocos2d-x 2.x game onto multiple platforms. As Marmalade is no more, what can I use for the latest Cocos2d-x 3.x?

Comment: how was Marmalade helping you? i mean, beyond Cocos2D - was it the Lua integration or?

Comment: @NasBanov Thank you for your comment. Marmalade (at least) allows me to easily manage the project for different platforms at the same time and keep all the project files perfectly in sync. (manage = cpp files to be compiled, configurations per each platform...) etc etc..